# How can I scrape Telegram users from a Telegram Group?

Tags: python, bots, telegram, telethon

So I've been trying for a long time, I found some pre-made programs, but they costs 100$. I've tried multiple apps and programs like Telegram Auto and Telegram Kit, but they cost a lot and I don't have such money right now.

I am trying to do it in Python and Telethon(Don't have a lot of experience in it)

I already made an app on telegram developer tools, got the API Number and Hash, and found the following code online

```
from telethon.tl.functions.messages import GetDialogsRequest
from telethon.tl.types import InputPeerEmpty
import csv

api_id = My API ID
api_hash = 'MY API HASH'
phone = 'MY PHONE'
client = TelegramClient(phone, api_id, api_hash)

client.connect()

chats = []
last_date = None
chunk_size = 200
groups=[]

result = client(GetDialogsRequest(
             offset_date=last_date,
             offset_id=0,
             offset_peer=InputPeerEmpty(),
             limit=chunk_size,
             hash = 0
         ))
chats.extend(result.chats)

for chat in chats:
    try:
        if chat.megagroup== True:
            groups.append(chat)
    except:
        continue

print('Choose a group to scrape members from:')
i=0
for g in groups:
    print(str(i) + '- ' + g.title)
    i+=1

g_index = input("Enter a Number: ")
target_group=groups[int(g_index)]

print('Fetching Members...')
all_participants = []
all_participants = client.get_participants(target_group, aggressive=True)

print('Saving In file...')
with open("members.csv","w",encoding='UTF-8') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f,delimiter=",",lineterminator="\n")
    writer.writerow(['username','user id', 'access hash','name','group', 'group id'])
    for user in all_participants:
        if user.username:
            username= user.username
        else:
            username= ""
        if user.first_name:
            first_name= user.first_name
        else:
            first_name= ""
        if user.last_name:
            last_name= user.last_name
        else:
            last_name= ""
        name= (first_name + ' ' + last_name).strip()
        writer.writerow([username,user.id,user.access_hash,name,target_group.title, target_group.id])      
print('Members scraped successfully.')
```

I entered My information, and I started the program, but I keep getting this error.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\User\Desktop\export.py", line 23, in 
    hash = 0
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\telethon\sync.py", line 39, in syncified
    return loop.run_until_complete(coro)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 579, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\telethon\client\users.py", line 64, in **call**
    result = await future
telethon.errors.rpcerrorlist.AuthKeyUnregisteredError: The key is not registered in the system (caused by GetDialogsRequest)

I searched everywhere for a fix or a tutorial and I didn't find anything. My only other choice was coming here.

Please Help.

Regards, Daniel

Comment: That's considered spam is and is against telegram's ToS. your account will be banned if you do so.

Answer (score 1):

Admittedly, the docs [aren't very clear](https://telethon.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/errors.html#telethon-errors) about what that error means, but from the looks of it, you might be suffering at the hands of an unmanaged resource. The docs themselves suggest [here:](https://telethon.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/client.html)

> The TelegramClient aggregates several mixin classes to provide all the common functionality in a nice, Pythonic interface. Each mixin has its own methods, which you all can use.
>
> In short, to create a client you must run:
>
> ```py
>    from telethon import TelegramClient
>
>    client = TelegramClient(name, api_id, api_hash)
>
>    async def main():
>        # Now you can use all client methods listed below, like for example...
>        await client.send_message('me', 'Hello to myself!')
>
>    with client:
>        client.loop.run_until_complete(main())
> ```
>
> You don’t need to import these AuthMethods, MessageMethods, etc. Together they are the TelegramClient and you can access all of their methods.
>
> See Client Reference for a short summary.

Consider using python's `with` statement to help manage `client`.

As an aside, did you know that one of the devs who contributed to Telethon has already written a [free and open source scraper?](https://github.com/expectocode/telegram-export)

Comment: The error comes directly from the telegram server and those aren't documented.